# nodejs express.js cannot get /1.jpg error

Tags: javascript

json worked (https://virus.has-no-bra.in/5aZ8fM0k5.png) but cannot get image (https://virus.has-no-bra.in/5aZ90HlbO.png) and i have 37.jpg file (https://virus.has-no-bra.in/5aZ9l_gt7.png)

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  list(`./img`,(images)=>{
  if(images.error) throw images.error;
  var floppa = images.files
  let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * floppa.length))

  var file = `domain${floppa[random]}`
  res.json(
    {
      image: file
    }
    )
});
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is list? And you have devetools